# Several questions on fullvisitorid

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Q1: is fullvisitorid unique? in scope of one GA account. is it nullable?

Q2: is fullvisitorid based on _utma cookie? if users(even registered users and logged in) visit from different browsers/computer/devices. will the fullvisitorid  be the same or not? if the existed _utma already linked to a userid, how will fullvisitorid affected, if not linked, how?

Q3: with analytics.js(not ga.js), if we enable feature of UserID,  when user visit our page anonymously (eg, not login) and we don't set UserID by calling ga("set","userid"......) will the fullvisitorid be null? or will it be linked with already existed _utma?

Q4: if one user visit the page  anonymously (eg, not login) first on a new computer which was used by other(and unfortunately, the computer owner accessed our page previously and hence _utma is already there),  and then login,  how will GA handle this? will it link the _utma to prior user or newly logged in user? any impact to both users' fullvisitored?

Q5: if we enable UserID feature in analytics.js, if one registered user access from different devices, will these sessions have different fullvisitorid or the same? and how can we join them together in big query since there's no userid column in bigquery table?

Q6: if we use ga.js on some pages and user analytics.js on some other pages in
the same domain(mistakenly), will it affect the accuracy?

Comment: Since you already pay for premium account, maybe try addressing these questions to the premium support.